# pywinauto gives RuntimeError: SendInput() inserted only 0 out of 2 keyboard events on Webex teams

Tags: python-3.x, ui-automation, pywinauto, webex

Running pywinauto using python script through **Task scheduler** gives the following error.
pywinauto version - 0.6.8
Python version - 3.12.0
Windows 10 (Virtual desktop)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Dashboard_checks\automation\dash_check_final.py", line 144, in 
sendWebexMessage(arrayStatus)
File "C:\Dashboard_checks\automation\dash_check_final.py", line 82, in sendWebexMessage
main_dlg.type_keys(msg_text,with_spaces=True,with_newlines=True,pause=0.1,with_tabs=True)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 964, in type_keys
keyboard.send_keys(
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\keyboard.py", line 713, in send_keys
k.run()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\keyboard.py", line 411, in run
raise RuntimeError('SendInput() inserted only ' + str(num_inserted_events) +
RuntimeError: SendInput() inserted only 0 out of 2 keyboard events

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=".*Webex")

main_dlg = app.top_window()
main_dlg.wait('visible')


def sendWebexMessage(arrayStatus):

    date_format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
    dt_format   = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'

    logging.info("sendWebexMessage:START")
    main_dlg.set_focus()
    #main_dlg.wait('visible')
    main_dlg.wait('enabled')
    
    time.sleep(15)
    logging.info("sendling Ctrl+Alt+I key")
    try:
        # sendling Ctrl+Alt+I key.
        # set focus on message window of Webex
        main_dlg.type_keys('^%I')

    except:
        logging.warning("sendling Ctrl+Alt+I key:Error")
            
    time.sleep(5)
    
    logging.info("sendling Z and Enter key")
    try:
        main_dlg.type_keys("Z")
        main_dlg.type_keys('{ENTER}')
    except:
        logging.warning("sending Z and Enter key:Error")


    for i in range (0,10): 
    
        logging.info("msg_text:"+msg_text)
        #print("msg_text:",msg_text)
        
              main_dlg.type_keys(msg_text,with_spaces=True,with_newlines=True,pause=0.1,with_tabs=True)
        main_dlg.type_keys('+{ENTER}')

    main_dlg.type_keys("\n",with_spaces=True,with_newlines=True,pause=0.1,with_tabs=True)

    logging.info("sendWebexMessage:END")
```

Edit 1: The code works if it is run manually.

Edit 2:
The task is being scheduled using the "Task Scheduler" GUI program

I am scheduling the program using a Batch (.bat) file
The command in the batch file is as follows:

```
"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\python.exe" "C:\automation\dash_check_v1.py"  > %LOGFILE% 2>&1
```

If I run the task immediately using the "Run" command within the Task Scheduler GUI the script works without any issue.
The issue occurs when I schedule it at a later time.

Comment: It is very interesting how the task is created in Task Scheduler: manually (with which params?) or by `Schtasks /Create` command (with which arguments?). It seems related to Task Scheduler somehow or which account is used.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov - I have edited my question based on you comment. Thanks.

Comment: OK, one more question: "later time" means "when desktop is locked"? Also I'd recommend to try checking task option "Run with highest privileges" at the first tab of the task properties.

Comment: Some of these hints may be useful as well (at least for making some things more clear): https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html

Comment: Got the same issue. After several months of successful execution this error suddenly appeared.  I ran my code on Windows using 3 techuser ADs and this error appeared on all of them twice - 6 times in general.  But after this when I ran it in Pycharm - it disapperaed and did not repeat yet.

So it came and disapperaed without any understandable reasons.  Users where hte same. Rights where the same.